# How to construct/describe the set of unions of all intervals $(a, b)$ of the real line?

Tags: general-topology

I have this problem in my textbook where I should verify whether a set $\Omega$ is a topological structure in $X=\mathbb R$. $\Omega$ is said to be "**the** set of **unions** of **all** intervals $(a, b): a, b \in \mathbb R$."

So before I start verifying the axioms of a topological structure I'm thinking I should better understand what exactly is the structure of $\Omega$. Even if I skip this part, I should verify that $\mathbb R \in \Omega$, so I'll have to know what is in $\Omega$ anyway.

I thought and thought and still cannot figure out what exactly is included in $\Omega$. An arbitrary union of such intervals always omits some elements, however I think of it. Since intervals of the types $(-\infty, a)$ and $(b, \infty)$ are by definition not included in $\Omega$, how would I prove that the whole $\mathbb R \in \Omega$?

English is not my native language and I haven't studied math in English in elementary school, so I believe the wording of the definition of $\Omega$ is confusing to me. It is said **"the set"**, which means that there's only one such set but how would I know that?

Then it is said "**all** intervals", which means that for every possible interval in $\mathbb R$ there is an element of $\Omega$, which includes that interval in its union.

Finally the definition says **"unions"** but not "**the** unions". If it were the latter, it would mean **all**, right? If it were the former, I just have to pair all intervals and their unions will be in $\Omega$ but that will not include the whole $\mathbb R$ ever.

Here my thoughts get more and more confusing as it seems.

Please help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Natural langage can be confusing. Let $I$ be the set of all the intervals $(a,b)$ (i.e. $I=\{(a,b) ; a,b \in \mathbb R$}). I think the definition of $\Omega$ is $$\Omega=\left\{ \bigcup_{(a,b) \in J} (a,b) ; J \subset I\right\} $$

Is that formulation clearer?

In particular, the union $$X=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} (-n,n)$$
belongs to $\Omega$... Is it clear for you that $X=\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: The set you have defined reads to me: "the set of unions of intervals $(a, b)$ from $\mathbb R$. This "**all**" in the original definition was the thing that confused me and I guess I looked into the wording more literally that I should had done. Anyway, your formulation is way clearer. As for why $X=\mathbb R$, I'm afraid to admit that I don't get it. The only explanation I can give to myself is that the sequence $(-1, 1) \subset (-2, 2) \subset ... \subset (-n, n) ... \subset$ has a limit, which is $\mathbb R$. So, the union $X$ is $\mathbb R$. Still I'm not entirely convinced that's it.

Comment: You can check the double inclusion if your not comfortable: $X\subset \mathbb R$ is obvious; let $x\in\mathbb R$, there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $x\in (-n,n)$. And $(-n,n)\subset X$. Hence $x\in X$ and so $\mathbb R \subset X$.

Comment: Yes, I see it this way. Your input has been of great help to me. I consider the question answered but before I go I want to ask you one last thing in this context. How would I prove that $\emptyset \in \Omega$ in this case? Is this rigorous and valid: \emptyset = $(a, a) \cup (b, b) \in \Omega$, for some $a, b \in \mathbb R$. I take $(a, a)$ and (b, b) to match the definition of $\Omega$.

Comment: Yes it is correct for $\emptyset \subset \Omega$. But you can consider $\emptyset = (0,0)$ since $(0,0)=\bigcup_{n\in\{0\}} (-n,n)$.